# How to define different css based on element changing number

Tags: html, css

I want that the Button element will take 100% of the container rather if it 1 2 or 3 in the container.

Here is the fiddle link: [Js Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/6qrt2nk7/#&togetherjs=rpISnIhkS3)

```
<div class="inputFieldBoolean buttonSeries" data-type="Boolean"><button class="true" data-value="1"><div class="sign"></div></button><button class="false" data-value="2"><div class="sign"></div></button><button class="notapplicable selected" data-value="3"><div class="sign"></div></button></div>

<div class="inputFieldBoolean buttonSeries" data-type="Boolean"><button class="true" data-value="1"><div class="sign"></div></button><button class="false" data-value="2"><div class="sign"></div></button></div>

<div class="inputFieldBoolean buttonSeries" data-type="Boolean"><button class="true" data-value="1"><div class="sign"></div></button></div>
```

Comment: Change the button width from 33% to 100% ?

Comment: @JohannKratzik Then the buttons will appear under each other... I want them to fit the container.

Comment: CSS does not count elements. There is no way for a button to know how many elements follow after it in the div. Give classes to the div that tell the css about the number of buttons.

Comment: In the Fiddle I see 6 buttons. So you want them all beside each other? Then divide 100/6 and set the width like this.

Comment: @JohannKratzik No. I want that rather if it's 1 or 2 or 3 Buttons they will always contain 100% of the div.

Comment: Got it :-) You can use jQuery to count the number of buttons and set their widths with the css() function

Comment: It is not allowed to have `div` inside a `button`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this via a script, or you can easily use `display: flex` to get all the buttons fit in the container:

So your CSS would be:

```
.inputFieldBoolean.buttonSeries {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.inputFieldBoolean.buttonSeries button {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    height: 42px;
    border: 1px solid #cdd6e9;
    background: #fcfcfc;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc 0%, #e6eef2 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fcfcfc), color-stop(100%, #e6eef2));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc 0%, #e6eef2 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc 0%, #e6eef2 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc 0%, #e6eef2 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fcfcfc 0%, #e6eef2 100%);
}
```

You can check the updated jsFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wv2f6315/1/).

More information about flexbox can be found at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

Generally, it is supported in most browsers versions, except for Internet Explorer 9 and below. I have also added prefixing for ensuring maximum compatibility.

[See also the CanIUse page](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) for flexbox.

Comment: display:table and 100% cells will also do the trick, but flexbox is a much cleaner (and future-proof) solution

Comment: I agree, @niloVelez

Comment: @Siavas Great answer, perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Your linked fiddle does not include the flexbox addition

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, @LGSon. I have corrected the link.

Answer (score 1):

First off, it is not allowed to have a `div` as a child element of a `button`, so if you need something similar, use a pseudo element, like `::before`, as shown in my below answer.

`flexbox` is of course the prefect choice, though for some of us we need to support IE9 and here is one, using `display: table` (the linear gradient won't work though, so for that a SVG is needed)

```css
.inputFieldBoolean.buttonSeries {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.inputFieldBoolean.buttonSeries div {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 1%;
  height: 42px;
}
.inputFieldBoolean.buttonSeries button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 42px;
  border: 1px solid #cdd6e9;
  background: #fcfcfc;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc 0%, #e6eef2 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fcfcfc), color-stop(100%, #e6eef2));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc 0%, #e6eef2 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc 0%, #e6eef2 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc 0%, #e6eef2 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fcfcfc 0%, #e6eef2 100%);
}
.inputFieldBoolean.buttonSeries button.sign::before {
  content: 'BuTtOn';
  color: #f00;
  border: 0 solid blue;
  border-width: 0 2px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputFieldBoolean buttonSeries" data-type="Boolean">
  <div>
    <button class="true sign" data-value="1"></button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="false sign" data-value="2"></button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="inputFieldBoolean buttonSeries" data-type="Boolean">
  <div>
    <button class="true sign" data-value="1"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

And here is another one, without the extra markup, using `:nth-child`

```css
.inputFieldBoolean.buttonSeries button {
  float: left;
  height: 42px;
  border: 1px solid #cdd6e9;
  background: #fcfcfc;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc 0%, #e6eef2 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #fcfcfc), color-stop(100%, #e6eef2));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc 0%, #e6eef2 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc 0%, #e6eef2 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fcfcfc 0%, #e6eef2 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fcfcfc 0%, #e6eef2 100%);
}
.inputFieldBoolean.buttonSeries button.sign::before {
  content: 'BuTtOn';
  color: #f00;
  border: 0 solid blue;
  border-width: 0 2px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.inputFieldBoolean.buttonSeries button:first-child:nth-last-child(1) {
  width: 100%;
}
.inputFieldBoolean.buttonSeries button:first-child:nth-last-child(2),
.inputFieldBoolean.buttonSeries button:first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ button {
  width: 50%;
}
.inputFieldBoolean.buttonSeries button:first-child:nth-last-child(3),
.inputFieldBoolean.buttonSeries button:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ button {
  width: 33.3333%;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputFieldBoolean buttonSeries" data-type="Boolean">
  <button class="true sign" data-value="1">
  </button>
  <button class="false sign" data-value="2">
  </button>
  <button class="notapplicable selected sign" data-value="3">
  </button>
</div>

<div class="inputFieldBoolean buttonSeries" data-type="Boolean">
  <button class="true sign" data-value="1">
  </button>
  <button class="false sign" data-value="2">
  </button>
</div>

<div class="inputFieldBoolean buttonSeries" data-type="Boolean">
  <button class="true sign" data-value="1">
  </button>
</div>
```